# Where in my calculations am I losing the fact that the differential equation is only stable when b is positive?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I have the following relative simple differential equation:

${{dR}\over{dt}} = a-bR$

(with a steady state of $0=a-bR \Leftrightarrow R = {{a}\over{b}}$).

The integrated form of the equation can be calculated like this:

$\int {{dR}\over{dt}} dt = \int (a-bR) dt$
$\Leftrightarrow R = at-bRt + C$
$\Leftrightarrow R+bRt = at + C$
$\Leftrightarrow R(1+bt) = at + C$
$\Leftrightarrow R = {{at + C}\over{1+bt}}$

I now let t in the integrated function "go towards" $\infty$; like this I can check, whether the steady state is stable or unstable; (when the function goes towards $\pm \infty$ the function/steady state is unstable, else-wise the function should diverge towards the steady state for sufficient large t's - which basically means, that the steady state is stable, since the system has only a single steady state...)

$lim_{t\to\infty} {{at}\over{1+bt}} = lim_{t\to\infty} a/b = a/b$

So indeed, the limes indicates that the steady state should be stable.

However the function is only stable if $b > 0$, since:

$d/dx (a-bx)=-b$
$\Rightarrow$ system is stable for $b > 0$
$\Rightarrow$ system is unstable for $b < 0$

Where in the above calculation am I loosing the conclusion that the steady state is only stable for $b > 0$?

Comment: The method you use to solve this is doomed since step one because $\int (a-bR) dt$ is not $at-bRt + C$, except when $R(t)$ is constant, which is not so in the present case. For a correct solution, use $$\int\frac{b\,dR}{a-bR}=\int b\,dt,$$ which yields $$\ln|a-bR(t)|=\ln|a-bR(0)|-bt.$$

Comment: Did is right. You cannot do your integration because $R$ is a function of variable $t$, and not a constant. Therefore, $\int Rdt \neq Rt$. For example, let $R(t) = e^{-t}$, then $$\int R dt = -e^{-t} \neq te^{-t}$$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you made a mistake in calculating the integral
\begin{align}
\int (a-bR) dt
\end{align}
Because you forget to integrate $R$ itself. So suppose $R=t^2$. Than you have the following 
\begin{align}
\int (a-bR) dt=\int (a-bt^2) dt=at-\frac{1}{3}bt^3\neq at-bt^3=at-bRt
\end{align}

Comment: no - because if this would be the case then the limes wouldn't necessarily converge against a steady state (in this case a/b) or $\pm \infty$ anymore. But this is something that has to be true. I furthermore think, that I'm indirectly removing the conclusion somehow; like if I have the following equation a/b=0 and I multiply with b to get the equation a=0; I could then conclude that b can take any values, but in fact, b still needs to be $\ne 0$ ...

Comment: Just rethought a bit - I have to admit, you are right ...